# How to calculate a unique "mode" from an array?

Tags: java, loops

I was tasked to find the mode of a given array (unspecified length). The mode is defined as the number that occurs the most *uniquely*. So, for example, the mode of an array [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 2.0] is 2.0. However, if there is not a unique number of that value, for example, [1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0], the program returns "no mode" or "Double.NaN" in my program.

I have written code that works for 3/4 test cases, but always messes up on catching the case where there are two modes that are the same.

```
public double mode() {

    double modeOne = data[0];
    double modeTwo = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int countOne = 0;
    int countTwo = 0;

    if(data.length == 1) { // special case: if array length is 1 the mode will always just be that value
        modeOne = data[0];
        return modeOne;
    } // end if

    for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { // pulling out first value
        double value = data[i];
        for(int n = 0; n < data.length; n++) { // comparing first value to all other values
            if (data[n] == value) {
                count ++; // adding onto a count of how many of the same number there are
            }
        }
        if(modeOne == value || modeTwo == value) { // move on if the modes already have that value
            continue;
        }
        if(count > countOne) { // setting the max count
            countTwo = countOne;
            countOne = count;
            modeTwo = modeOne;
            modeOne = value;
        }
        else if(count > countTwo) { // setting second highest count
            countTwo = count;
            modeTwo = value;
        }
    } // end for
    if(countOne == 1) { // if all the modes are just one
        return Double.NaN;
    }
    if(countOne == countTwo) { // if there are two of the same modes
        return Double.NaN;
    }
    else {
        return modeOne;
    }
} //end MODE
```

For this test case:

```
double[] data = {1,2,2,3,3,4};
Stat stat1 = new Stat(data);
System.out.println("stat1 mode = " + stat1.mode());
```

I expect "NaN" but it returns 4. However, it works for the case below:

```
double[] data = {-5.3, 2.5, 88.9, 0, 0.0, 28, 16.5, 88.9, 109.5, -90, 88.9};
Stat stat1 = new Stat(data);
System.out.println("stat1 mode = " + stat1.mode());
```

The expected output is 88.9, which the program does correctly output.

Comment: Does *most uniquely* mean *most frequently*?

Comment: Yes - most frequently but also there should not be another value within that array with the same mode. If that makes sense. So [1.0,1.0,2.0,2.0,3.0] has no mode, because the 1.0 and 2.0 both occur the same amount of times.

Comment: Couldn't you simply scan the array and save the frequency of each encountered number in a list. Then order the list on decreasing frequency. If this list has more than 1 element and the first 2 elements have the same frequency, then return NaN. Otherwise return the first element from the list.

Comment: @RobertKock yes thats what i thought ... OP is doing it in very complex way

Comment: Should probably go with a Map<Double, Integer> and scan through once, incrementing the value each time the key appears in your data set.

Comment: How would I determine the frequency? This is for a school project, so we aren't allowed to use any Array methods. Only basic functions. Would I just count the frequency using a loop? And just simplify the cases in my code? @RobertKock

Comment: Gotta love school projects that give you a complex multi-tool to learn and tell you the only way you may use it is as a hammer :p

Comment: You're not even allowed to use `Collection`s?

Comment: You can find "frequency" in a `for-loop` simlpe @FrancesBrown

Comment: @Benson99 Exactly!! We had a huge project with 400+ lines of code, because they didn't allow us to use multiple classes and object oriented programming.

Comment: Nope :( @RobertKock

Comment: What about changing school?

Comment: hahahhhahahahahahhaha... @RobertKock you got me ... ;)

Comment: And seriously... I've been there.  I've gone to the dean because I paid 12k to go to school and we wasted 3 weeks toiling over using programming methods from the early 90s.

Comment: Hahhaahaha that's too good @RobertKock

Comment: @Benson99 Yes!! If there's a more efficient way to do things, lets save stress and time and use it! its 2019!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go no `Collection` etc... pure hard programming :)

```
public double mode(double[] data)
{
    if(data.length==1)
        return data[0];
    double temp;
    double [] fr = new double [data.length];  //store frequency
    int visited = -1;  

    for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    {           
        int count = 1;  
        for(int j = i+1; j < data.length; j++)
        {  
            if(data[i] == data[j])
            {  
                count++;   
                fr[j] = visited;  
            }  
        }  
        if(fr[i] != visited)  
            fr[i] = count;  
    }  


    for (int i = 0; i < fr.length; i++)   // sort array in decreasing order
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < fr.length; j++) 
        {
            if (fr[i] < fr[j]) 
            {
                temp = data[i];
                data[i] = data[j];
                data[j] = temp;

                temp = fr[i];
                fr[i] = fr[j];
                fr[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    if(fr[0] == fr[1])
        return Double.NaN;
    else
        return data[0];

}
```

Comment: This so helpful!! The way you wrote the return statements is so much cleaner and simpler. The idea of storing a frequency hadn't occurred to me, but it helps so much. Thank you!!

Comment: Now, you can change the school hahaha... Let me tell you schools are same everywhere... it is you who have to figure out the problem.. thats what make a you a programmer .. Happy coding :)

Comment: As hard as it is, it does help me *really* solidify the basic concepts for a programming foundation... thanks again! :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approaching using Streaming API.  However, I took the definition of modes which is a set rather than a single number.

```
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.OptionalLong;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertFalse;

public class ModeTest {

    private <T extends Number> Set<T> modes(T... input) {
        return modes(Arrays.stream(input));
    }

    /**
     * Calculate the modes of a numeric stream.  The modes are the values that occurs most often. If no number in the
     * stream is repeated, then all the numbers in the stream are modes.
     *
     * @param input stream of numbers
     * @param <T>   number type
     * @return modes.
     */
    private <T extends Number> Set<T> modes(Stream<T> input) {

        // transform the input to a map containing the counted entries
        final Set<Map.Entry<T, Long>> countedEntries = input
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
            .entrySet();

        // Figure out the max value
        final OptionalLong max = countedEntries
            .parallelStream()
            .mapToLong(Map.Entry::getValue)
            .max();

        // Handle the case where the stream was empty
        if (max.isEmpty()) {
            return Set.of();
        }

        return countedEntries
            .parallelStream()
            .filter(e -> e.getValue() == max.getAsLong())
            .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());

    }

    @Test
    public void oneMode() {
        final Double[] input = new Double[]{1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0};
        assertEquals(modes(input), Set.of(2.0));
    }

    @Test
    public void multipleModes() {
        final Stream<Double> input = Stream.of(1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0);
        assertEquals(modes(input), Set.of(2.0, 3.0));
    }

    @Test
    public void allSingles() {
        final Stream<Double> input = Stream.of(1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 2.0, 3.0);
        assertEquals(modes(input), Set.of(1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 2.0, 3.0));
    }

    @Test
    public void largeRandomSet() {
        Integer[] randoms = new Integer[204800];
        for (int i = randoms.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
            randoms[i] = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(200);
        }
        assertFalse(modes(randoms).isEmpty());
    }

    @Test
    public void emptyStream() {
        final Stream<Double> input = Stream.of();
        assertEquals(modes(input), Set.of());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I was in the mood for a small challenge, I did write my own solution using a Map to count the individual values.

Then you retrieve the highest count available and iterate over the map again to determine if multiple entries have the same highest count, if so, you'll return NaN.

```
public static double calculateMode(double[] numbers) {
    Map<Double, Integer> lookupMap = new TreeMap<>();

    for (double number : numbers) {
        if (lookupMap.get(number) != null) {
            lookupMap.put(number, lookupMap.get(number) + 1);
        } else {
            lookupMap.put(number, 1);
        }
    }

    int max = -1;
    double maxKey = Double.NaN;
    for (Entry<Double, Integer> entry : lookupMap.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getValue() > max) {
            max = entry.getValue();
            maxKey = entry.getKey();
        }
    }

    int foundMax = 0;

    for (Entry<Double, Integer> entry : lookupMap.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getValue() == max) {
            foundMax++;
        }
    }

    if (foundMax > 1) {
        return Double.NaN;
    }

    return maxKey;

}
```

Method call:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double[] data = {1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4};
    double[] data2 = {-5.3, 2.5, 88.9, 0, 0.0, 28, 16.5, 88.9, 109.5, -90, 88.9};
    System.out.println("Expected NaN - and was: " + calculateMode(data));
    System.out.println("Expected 88.90 - and was: " + calculateMode(data2));
}
```

Outputs:

```
Expected NaN - and was: NaN
Expected 88.90 - and was: 88.9
```

Comment: She can't use the Collections API.

Comment: Well did she confirm that? I thought only array functions are affected...

Comment: I love the way this works! So much cleaner. Would there be a way to do it without the Collections?

Comment: Yeah.… I was gonna do what you did as well until she commented again

Comment: @maio290 Unfortunately yes. :(

Comment: That's why I've had so much trouble trying to find a similar solution on the forum already - there are terrific solutions but not quite for the constraints I have.

Comment: Good that other people had some time yesterday. But really, your school is kinda weird. :/

Answer (score 1):

So I felt challenged as well and got a solution without the use of `Collection`s.
Not a really nice solution but it seems to work:

```
public class TestMode
{
  private static class NumberFrequency
  {
    double number;
    int    frequency;
  }

  public static double calculateMode(double[] numbers)
  {
    // Maybe array empty
    if ((numbers == null) || (numbers.length == 0))
      return Double.NaN;

    // Initialize array with frequencies
    NumberFrequency[] array;
    int               size = 0;
    array = new NumberFrequency[numbers.length];

    // Loop over numbers determining frequencies
    for (double number : numbers)
    {
      // Maybe encountered before
      int index;
      for (index = 0; index < size; index++)
      {
        if (array[index].number == number)
          break;
      }

      // Update array
      NumberFrequency elm;
      if (index == size)
      {
        elm = new NumberFrequency();
        elm.number = number;
        elm.frequency = 0;
        array[index] = elm;
        size++;
      }
      else
        elm = array[index];
      elm.frequency += 1;

    } // for all numbers

    // Initialize element with highest frequency
    int index_highest;
    int highest_freq;
    int nr_occurs;
    index_highest = 0;
    highest_freq = array[0].frequency;
    nr_occurs = 1;

    // Search 'better' element
    int counter;
    for (counter = 1; counter < size; counter++)
    {
      if (array[counter].frequency > highest_freq)
      {
        index_highest = counter;
        highest_freq = array[counter].frequency;
        nr_occurs = 1;
      }
      else if (array[counter].frequency == highest_freq)
        nr_occurs++;
    }

    // Return result
    if (nr_occurs == 1)
      return array[index_highest].number;
    else
      return Double.NaN;

  } // calculateMode

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    double[] data = {1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4};
    double[] data2 = {-5.3, 2.5, 88.9, 0, 0.0, 28, 16.5, 88.9, 109.5, -90, 88.9};
    System.out.println("Expected NaN - and was: " + calculateMode(data));
    System.out.println("Expected 88.90 - and was: " + calculateMode(data2));  }

} // class TestMode
```

Comment: Well, it is doing purpose, but its very complex... you can see my answer, kept as short as possible, in the boundary of NO API PONLY HARD PROGRAMMING

Comment: Oooh I didn't even consider the empty array option. The encountered before option also increases efficiency which I like. Thanks so so much!! :)

Answer (score 1):

To add one more alternative and because I also felt challenged as well:

The general idea is to generate a frequency array, fore the given example above

```
 [1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0]
 [1,    2,   2,   2,   2]
```

which indicates how many times the element at the same index is in the input, then find the max value in the frequency array, and finally check if all values with the same frequency are equal.

```
public static double mode(double [] data) {  
   if(data == null || data.length < 1){
       return Double.NaN;
   }      
   int [] freq = new int [data.length]; 
   for(int i = 0; i<data.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<data.length; j++){
            if(data[i]==data[j]){
                freq[i]++;
            }
        }
    }
    int max = 0;
    double mode = data[0];
    for(int i = 0; i<freq.length; i++){
        if(freq[i]>max){
            max = freq[i];
            mode = data[i];
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i<freq.length; i++){
        if(freq[i] == max){
            if(mode != data[i]){
               return Double.NaN;
            }
        }
    }
    return mode;
}
```